# Calculate the entropy of Turkish alphabet and compare with the entropy of English alphabet with using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, signal-analysis, linear-algebra

Calculate the entropy of Turkish alphabet and compare with the entropy of English alphabet with using Matlab?
  How can ı do this question anybody help please?..

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you a hint: You need the probability distribution of the alphabet (English and Turkish). For English see the [Wikipedia "Letter Frequency" page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency). Now it's possible to compute the Entropy of this distribution.

Note that this is a rough approximation (and an upper bound) since in practice, the letters of a word (and a sentence) are correlated. So, for example, in English the letter 'q' is always followed by 'u'. Thus, the entropy of a source producing English documents is strictly less than the one you'll get from looking at single letters.